# How to override background of Bootstrap Material Design theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I've built a website using bootstrap, and I now want to use the [Bootstrap Material Design theme](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) for its sexy components. So I included the css and js in my `<head>`, which immediately changes a lot of things in my website, such as the background and the navbar.

Unfortunately I do not want to use the background or the navbar of the theme. Does anybody know how I can override or "disable" the theme's navbar and background?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: yes, comment that part out of the css

Comment: @ScottSelby - But I don't want to do that because the theme might get updates and I use a CDN.

Comment: so you do this order , bootstrap css then this theme you want , then the css overriding the parts you don't like.

Comment: you asked a pretty bad question that could of very easily been solved on your own with google.  Then you get a couple good answers and don't accept any or upvote or leave any comments.  Thats not very nice,  people posting answers I think were going out of their way to ignore to low question quality and still answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it by going into your new theme. Find the background and navbar in the css file of your new theme and simply use "!important" to override this.

Example:

```
background: white !important;
```

Comment: `!important` is a bad practice. Avoid using overrides when localization solves your problem.

Comment: Yes but for this case,  the asker asked to override the previous theme. @DaveAlperovich

Comment: The answer was accepted, so it met asker needs. But it's a bad practice. Same could have been accomplished with specificity.

Answer (score 1):

find all unwished components, copy and paste them into your own css file, change the values and include it as latest into the header section. hope this helps